# How to encrypt peer data exchange?

Tags: encryption, aes, udp

The situation currently is as follows:

- All our devices in the same network broadcast their state (alongside with unique IDs) over the network. They also listen in for broadcasts of others. Everything is plaintext.
- All the devices have a configuration which contains IDs of devices they are interested in, and pieces of their state they need for co-operative work. They use this to extract the interesting data from the datagrams.
- Devices can go on-line or off-line unpredictably. One device going off-line doesn't significantly impact others who use its data ("peer is off-line" as deduced from lack of messages from said peer is a valid, expectable state).
- The entire configuration, including assigning IDs and entering peer IDs is done manually, per network, and with no real risk of 3rd party intervening in any way.

Currently it appears someone (legally) plugged into the network is snooping on the messages. We'd like to put an end to it and make the broadcasts encrypted: give each device an individual key (created at configuration time), and added to "interested peers" alongside with peer ID of "interesting peer" at configuration time. There's no need for asymmetric ciphers and mistrust as to identity of a device as the configuration is installed via [sneakernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet). I've got a nice AES implementation suitable for our purposes, but the [encryption modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Confidentiality_only_modes) gave me a pause. It has ECB, CBC and CTR, and cooking our own CFB seems trivial, but:

- Since the devices can join at any time, and they have no clue how many messages the peers had sent in the past (never mind a message *can* get lost; UDP broadcast), it looks like all: CFB, CBC and CTR seem right out; the peer needs to be able to plug into any point of the broadcast and won't know messages that had been sent while it was off.
- ECB comes with a warning that it does not hide data patterns well and is not recommended for use in cryptographic protocols

The devices include a timestamp in the message, and *can* include anything else if needed, so multiple messages being identical isn't really an issue. So asking here how to approach it:

- stop worrying and go with ECB, not a problem in my case?
- make a *short* sequence of CTR; have the newcomer lose a couple first broadcasts (failing to decrypt them) until it arrives at one it can decrypt successfully and sync up to it?
- some yet different approach which would solve my issue, and I'm not aware of?

Comment: Encryption modes are applied to a single message that is split into several blocks. It is reinitialized at each new message, so adding new devices should not be an issue here. The first iteration relies on an *Initialization Vector* (IV) which is reinitialized at each new message. EDIT: see @foreverska answer that makes the same statement. See also for alternatives.

Comment: Additionally, asymmetric encryption could still be useful as you may not trust your initial transport medium or anyone joining the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having trouble following this post and I think it's because there is a misunderstanding of the nature of the "chaining" aspect.

Blocks within a single ciphertext are chained together, not between ciphertexts.  Each message should have a distinct IV and start from zero in the encryption process, no matter the mode.  ECB's issue arises from a lack of IV, not the lack of chaining.

If the whole ciphertext cannot fit in a single message, chaining might shoot one in the foot in an unreliable transport but a stream cipher might not be particularly useful either in that case.

As for a modern, streaming cipher with an IV, AES-GCM or ChaCha are notable alternatives.